# Why dataAnnotations dosen't valid the CourseList porperty of the Stuent?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations, componentmodel

When I used data `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, I had a problem. I defined a Student class that contains 2 attributes; one is the Name attribute and the other is the CourseList attribute; when I use the Validator.TryValidateObject method to verify the Sutent instance, there is no effect on CourseList. Who can help me

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var user = new Stuent();
            var context = new ValidationContext(user, null, null);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(user, context, results, true);
       }
}
public class Stuent
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Course> CourseList { get; set; }

}
public class Course
{
    [Required]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

}
```

}

[Click on me by clicking on the mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tjlP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Custom Validation attribute to validate your CourseList Property.

I have made some changes in your above code and also create a custom validation attribute. Please check [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWwHUH).

You can run and check this code that it will show validation message when you don't assign value to CourseName property.